# image texture on plane leaves average color of image in 3d-view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image

When I place an image on to a plane ( lets say it's a striped black and white pattern ) all I see in the rendered viewport is a GREY! color.  As if the colors of the image are mixed.
When I place an image texture of a blue sky and green field I see a blue-ish / green-ish color in mij Cycles rendered viewport.

I don't understand how to add a screenshot of my Blender scene to this message, but I have one if you need more information.  Just mail me:  eluttger@gmail.com

Thanks for the help, Emil

Comment: Use the image icon upper left of the text box (create or edit question/answer) to upload an image. And if you don't want spam, delete youe Email adress!

Comment: use this site [pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) to upload the scene

Answer (score 5):

When using an *Image Texture* you need to **UV unwrap your mesh**.

To do this, go into edit mode, select all vertices, and press <kbd>U</kbd> *> Unwrap*.

[image: Unwrap GIF]

What is happening, is Blender has no coordinates to map the texture to, so it takes the **average image color** and uses that as the texture. When you UV unwrap the mesh, you are telling Blender what vertices go where in relation to the texture, and Blender can then project the texture onto the mesh.

If you now go to the *UV/Image Editor* you can see and edit how your mesh has been unwrapped:

[image: UV Edit]

Comment: Thanks!  And then?... What do I do? ( In the Image Editor ), do I "SaveImage"or "Pack Image"or Ëxport UV layout"?...

Comment: Just edit the UV's, don't save the image, it already exists :)

Comment: @Emil Did this solve your issue? If so, please accept the question.